# Problems with hector_slam Tutorials MappingUsingLoggedData

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, hector-slam, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run : hector_slam Tutorials MappingUsingLoggedData with Hydro.  After I launch everything, I don't get any thing on Rviz.
Here is the warning that I am getting:
[ INFO] [1414325137.230751975]: Geotiff node started [ WARN] [1414325156.252540097]: No transform between frames /map and scanmatcher_frame available after 20.003600 seconds of waiting. This warning only prints once. [ INFO] [1414325181.258100206, 1310297993.109858243]: Finished waiting for tf, waited 45.009179 seconds SearchDir angle change too large SearchDir angle change too large SearchDir angle change too large SearchDir angle change too large

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195715/problems-with------hector_slam-----tutorials-----mappingusingloggeddata/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-10-23**:
can you write more about error  like commands used , rqt_graph, frames.pdf

ps: check you have proper frames and topic set to display map(incase just display problem.).

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2014-10-26**:
Here is the error that I am getting: [ INFO] [1414325137.230751975]: Geotiff node started
[ WARN] [1414325156.252540097]: No transform between frames /map and scanmatcher_frame available after 20.003600 seconds of waiting. This warning only prints once.
[ INFO] [1414325181.258100206, 1310297993.109858243]: Finished waiting for tf, waited 45.009179 seconds
SearchDir angle change too large
SearchDir angle change too large
SearchDir angle change too large
SearchDir angle change too large

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-10-26**:
It shows scan match is not well, may be you are moving in long straight corridor or less laser scan rate or very fast moving vehicle.

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2014-10-26**:
I did manage to get the tutorial.launch running without any errors, but I still don't have anything showing on Rviz.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-10-26**:
try saving map with mapsaver to check if problem with just visualisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was crowding my CPU too much, and was not giving mapsaver long enough.  I shutdown some of the processes running on the CPU and everything worked ok.

---

Originally posted by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) with karma: 111 on 2014-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0